# Replacing Values in CSV export

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, csv

I am using the CSVHelper Component from NuGet.  I have all of my data exporting successfully.  However, I have several fields that are boolean type and return "true"/"false" to the csv file.  My project requires that instead I output either "1" or "0" instead of "true"/"false".  What is the easiest way to achieve this?

```
    var AllRecords = surveyResponseRepository.Get()
                    .Where(r => r.ProgramId == ProgramId);

    string uniqueID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); 

    var appData = Server.MapPath("~/CsvExport/" + uniqueID + ".csv");

    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(new StreamWriter(appData)))

    {
        csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
        csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ',';
        csv.WriteRecords(AllRecords);
    }
```

Comment: Are you inserting these values into a Class?

Comment: No I was not, just exporting the data.  Would it be best to create a sort of ViewModel to adapt the data?

Comment: You could stage the data in a class and then manipulate it the way you want and then finally export it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could inherit CsvWriter and override WriteField to something like this:

```
    public override void WriteField( string field )
    {
        if (field.ToLower() == bool.TrueString.ToLower())
             field = "1";
        if (field.ToLower() == bool.FalseString.ToLower())
             field = "0";
        base.WriteField(field);
    }
```

Comment: Looks slick, but I'm getting "Error 15 A member 'CMESurvey.HtmlHelpers.CsvBoolean.WriteField(string)' marked as override cannot be marked as new or virtual"

Comment: Sorry, just remove virtual keyword from the method signature

Comment: Now I'm getting "Error 15 'CsvHelper.CsvWriter' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments"

Comment: Ok, that means you should create constructor for your class which has just the same signature as the base one. Something like the following one: public CsvWriterEx(....params here...) : base(..param names here..) {}

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each record in AllRecords, find the fields that are represented by boolean values, and use the following to convert to integer values:

```
Convert.ToInt32(booleanValue);
```